# How to use single Fragment for all the pages in the ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

In my application I have to show the Student details in `ViewPager`. I used one fragment (say `StudentPageFragment`) and I write widget initializing code in `onCreateView()` like:

```
public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    StudentPageFragment f = new StudentPageFragment();
    return f;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.stud_list_page,
            null);
    // initialize all widgets here
    displayStudentDetails();
    return root;
}

protected void displayStudentDetails() {
    ArrayList<Student>studList = User.getStudentsList();
    if (studList != null) {
        int loc = (pageIndex * 3);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (loc < studList.size()) {
                // populate data in view
            }
            loc++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have maintained a common `ArrayList<Student>` object which holds all the student objects.

And In `displayStudentDetails()` methods, I populate the first 3 Student objects there. If we swipe next page the same fragment should called the displayed next 3 Student objects.

And in `ViewPagerAdapter` class:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment f = new Fragment();
    f = StudentPageFragment.newInstance(_context);
    StudentPageFragment.setPageIndex(position);
    return f;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return User.getPageCount();// this will give student list size divided by 3
}
```

Now my problem is all the pages holds first 3 student details. Please provide me the best way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now my problem is all the pages holds first 3 student details.

If this is happening, most likely your `displayStudentDetails()` method only gets the first three student details that you keep seeing and doesn't take in consideration the position(and the student details that come with that position) of the `Fragment` in the `ViewPager`. As you didn't posted the method I can't recommend a solution.

> I have maintained a common ArrayList object which holds all
>   the student objects.

Where did you do this and how do you store that list?

> f = StudentPageFragment.newInstance(_context);

Please don't pass the `Context` to your fragments as the `Fragment` class has a reference to the `Context`/`Activity` through the `getActivity()` method that you should use instead.

You should build the Fragments like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return StudentPageFragment.newInstance(position);
}
```

where the `newInstance()` method will be:

```
public static Fragment newInstance(int position) {
      StudentPageFragment f = new StudentPageFragment();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt("position", position);
      f.setArguments(args); 
      return f;
}
```

You'll then retrieve the `position` and use it in the `Fragment`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.stud_list_page,
            container, false);
    // initialize all widgets here        
    displayStudentDetails(getArguments().getInt("position"));
    return root;
}
```

In the `displayStudentPosition` you could get the values like this:

```
protected void displayStudentDetails(int position) {
        ArrayList<Student>studList = User.getStudentsList();
        if (studList != null) {
        for (int i = position; i < 3 && i < studList.size; i++) {
             // populate data
        } 
        } 
}
```

Comment: I have posted my displayStudentDetails()

Comment: In FragmentActivity, I retrieve Student list from server and parsed it and maintained in User class

Comment: @Sridhar As you get the student's data from the server on a background thread, the data isn't probably available when the `ViewPager` is shown to the user, right?

Comment: You are right, I set up the viewpager after I parsed the data from the server

Comment: @Sridhar Have you debugged the `displayStudentDetails` method and check what values do the `loc` and `pageIndex` have? Why not simply pass the `position` value that you pass to the `Fragment` in the adapter(which you should do through a Bundle anyway) and use that in the displaystudentdetails method?

Comment: i have passed the page index through adapter by setArgument method. How to get the argument in the Fragment class